# Is there a way in Rubymine to pass the currently opened file as an argument?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rubymine

I was hoping to create a custom rake task that I can run `rubycritic` against the currently opened file.

I created a rake task and set up Rubymine's configuration to add the rake task so I can execute it via the IDE.

What I can't figure out is how to pass the currently opened file into the arguments of the rake task.  Is there a way to do this?  I'm assuming some sort of global variable like $CURRENT_FILE or something?

Is this the easiest way of running `rubycritic` for an open file in Rubymine?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You can try using built-in macros (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/2022.3/built-in-macros.html), e.g. $FileName$

Comment: @Olivia, Thanks, that seems to be exactly what I am looking for.  I tried putting $FileDir$ in the rake task arguments but in the rake task it comes in as the string "$FileDir$".  Do you have to enable macros somehow?